# How do (CVE patched) package versions relate?

Tags: cve, package-manager

Given the real-life example of an announced vulnerability fix, e.g. the latest [openssl vulnerability fixes](https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160926.txt), and a Distro's reported throughput of the fix, e.g. GNU/Linux [Debian's response to CVE-2016-6309](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-6309):

```
wheezy              1.0.1e-2+deb7u20  fixed
wheezy  (security)  1.0.1t-1+deb7u1   fixed
```

I have two questions:

1. Will having installed (a possible future) version 1.0.1e-2+deb7u**21** *per definition* contain the (or better) fix too, it being the younger version (note: I'm using a hypothetical example, u21 does not exist yet, as my question is generic not specific)?
2. What is the difference between `wheezy` and `wheezy (security)` in the specific example (GNU/Linux Debian). Sometimes the "security one" seems to refer to a younger version version, sometimes to an older, I'm lost..

If anyone could shed some light on these one for me.. that would be appreciated!

Comment: Also if anyone know the answer to my, more specific (but very related!), [question I posted in the Raspberrypi stack exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55548/how-do-raspbian-openssl-relate-to-debian-openssl-packages); Don't hesitate to teach the h* out of me! :P

Comment: If you check that page carefully, you'll see a note saying "openssl <not-affected> (Only affects 1.1)" in the end, so in this case "fixed" means *we have checked this vulnerability and did nothing about it*.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - Thanks for noticing and informing us! I upvoted your comment (but accidentally downvoted, and now it is impossible to upvote again). It is not answering the questions per se, but it was a very informative comment about a related detail that I would otherwise have missed. So thanks! What would you say about [what I posted below](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137930/how-do-cve-patched-package-versions-relate#comment257619_137956)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: In principle `u20` and any package with a higher number should not be vulnerable (hell, `u1` and any higher should not be vulnerable since the upstream version of the package does not change and `u1` is not vulnerable).  That is, unless `VVV` (the upstream version, see below) changes or you change your Debian release, in which case a different numbering is used (see below for an elaborate explanation of version conventions).  That is true in 99.9% of cases, but developers make mistakes and sometimes later changes awaken old vulnerabilities.  Yet, that is quite rare and in such a case a new CVE is raised.

### Debian package naming convention

Heh, you will probably find this frustrating but the Debian FAQ explains the version part of the package as:

> The VVV component is the version number specified by the upstream developer. There are no standards in place here, so the version number may have formats as different as "19990513" and "1.3.8pre1".
>
> The RRR component is the Debian revision number, and is specified by the Debian developer (or an individual user if he chooses to build the package himself). This number corresponds to the revision level of the Debian package, thus, a new revision level usually signifies changes in the Debian Makefile (debian/rules), the Debian control file (debian/control), the installation or removal scripts (debian/p*), or in the configuration files used with the package.

But wait, what are those `VVV` and `RRR`?  The full naming convention is:

```
foo_VVV-RRR_AAA.deb
```

`AAA` is simple, it is the architecture.  `VVV` comes from the upstream developer, i.e. from the openssl developers in your case (e.g. `1.0.1` or `1.0.1t`, see [here](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.1-notes.html)).

Last comes the `RRR` which is left to the person packaging the `.deb`, and it really be anything.  On the other hand Debian packagers normally follow the debian version (`deb7` for wheezy, `deb8` for jessie) plus some update number.  The update number does not need to be sequential, it just need to be higher than the previous one.  This is likely because a packager will have failed test builds of his packages*.

In summary, there is nothing that links the `.deb` version string and the CVEs it includes.  You do need to go and read the release notes.  Moreover, often you need to read the release notes of the packager and of the upstream developer (the packager will often include a link to th release notes of the upstream developer).

### (security) repositories

What `wheezy (security)` means instead of plain `wheezy` is that your Debian has the `security` repository installed as one of the repositories for `apt`.  This is normally performed with:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
```

The guys at security.debian.org work on CVEs and produce all those CVE reports in the [debian security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/).  They update packages for old and new Debian versions as needed for the security purposes.  Using your example CVE: openssl in `jessie` is pretty new, in `jessie (security)` is newer, in `wheezy (security)` is new, but `wheezy` still uses a rather old version.

This allows sysadmins that use `wheezy` to get security updates without the need to upgrade to `jessie`.  Debian is incredibly robust and stable, and there are sysadmins that may wish not to update their packages with security updates fearing that code changes will make things fail (they simply do not enable the security repositories).

Now, the security guys will update an older package if it is needed, [they prefer backporting the package](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#oldversion).  Yet, sometimes it is needed to update `VVV`, for example the openssl at `wheezy (security)` is at `1.0.1t` whilst on `wheezy` is at `1.0.1e`, likely because of [this CVE](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-2107).

Therefore, we can say that `wheezy (security)` is more dangerous in terms of backward compatibility then plain `wheezy` but safer than upgrading to `jessie`.  As far as I am aware if you use just plain `wheezy` or plain `jessie` (you only have the `stable` repository in `sources.list`) you will **never** receive a `VVV` update through `apt`, you will only get updates to the `RRR` part.

Note that thanks to the fact that it is a different set of people that work on the `(security)` repositories and the normal repositories, funny things happen.  [Here is a CVE in which the (security) package is vulnerable but the normal one isn't](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-6323), in this case it is fine because `VVV` is the same and `RRR` of the non-security package is higher and will be selected by `apt` as the newest update available.

Related / References:

- [Debian packaging basics (FAQ)](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)
- [Debian package naming convention on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97289/debian-package-naming-convention)

---

<sub>* I cannot tell specifically for Debian but one recent packaging adventure I watched was Vim 8.  The upstream developer patches came very fast and the testing repository of Arch had: `vim-8.0.0001` => `vim-8.0.0003` => `vim-8.0.0005`.  The last one, `vim-8.0.0005`, was moved into the `extra` public repository. Therefore packagers often jump release numbers because the package is updated before it is allowed to leave the testing package repositories.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration on the naming convention. I got that (now / in general). The question is about application convention / assumptions though, *given the versions*: Should 1.0.1e-2+deb7 **u21** (or *.u32 for that matter) to be expected to have included a fix build into the 1.0.1e-2+deb7 **u20**?

Comment: @woosting - Eyup, that is the case.  In principle **u20** and any package with a higher number should have that fix (unless `VVV` changes or you change your debian release, in which case a different numbering is used).  That is true in 99.9% of cases, but developers make mistakes and sometimes later changes awaken old vulnerabilities.  Yet, that is quite rare and in such a case a new CVE is raised.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm still puzzled by about the 2nd subquestion though. Maybe [this report](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-7547) is more illustrative: `Jessie (security)` reports the fix to have landed in `2.19-18+deb8u3` (u3), yet for the normal Jessie this would be `2.19-18+deb8u6` (u6)? Say I install `2.19-18+deb8u5` (u5). Would it have the vulnerability fixed? Or better yet; what (and why) is the difference between `Jessie` and `Jessie (security)` in this context (I realize this may be too much of  Debian specific question but you seem knowledgeable in the area)?

Comment: @woosting - Oh cool.  `jessie (security)` means the package number you get the fix if you have `deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib` in `sources.list`.  And plain `jessie` is the package you get that if you don't have it in `sources.list`.  The [security guys backport the security fixes into older versions](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#oldversion) and therefore there are sometimes discrepancies between the two.  Note that depending on how much code is changed "older version" may have different numbering, making some inconsistency.

Comment: Ah! So for [the example](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-7547) the conservative sysadmin would stay with the `1.0.1e-2+deb7u20` to keep changes minimal (integrational stability?), whereas a lenient one would have `http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib` in its source-list to upgrade to `1.0.1t-1+deb7u1` (a package with more rigorously changed code). @grochmal Thanks for "staying with me here"! Do you want me to "answer my own question", or do *you* want your credits and do it (if I find your answer in the morning I'll up-vote it, otherwise I'll summarize).

Comment: @woosting - Yeah, that's more-or-less that. I did a revamp and added some more links.  I'll just reiterate one thing from the previous comment: if debian release (wheezy/jessie) and `VVV` matches, then `RRR` is one numbering.  If either release of `VVV` is different you cannot rely on `RRR` to tell you anything.

Comment: I added [your comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137930/how-do-cve-patched-package-versions-relate/137956#comment257601_137956) (that explicitly answered the first sub-question) to your answer. It is now waiting on a "peer review", after-which I'll mark it as the (very fine - I might add) answer to my questions! EDIT: My edit to your answer got rejected though... weird... as that edit is explicitly done to have it included in the answer.. not sure what to do now..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46010/discussion-between-woosting-and-grochmal).